# Is there a way to automatically turn text into hyperlinks in Processing?

Tags: text, hyperlink, processing

I'm brand new to programming in general, but specifically Processing, and I need some help on a final project for my digital media class! Using a QR Code Reader library, I've made a sketch in Processing that successfully reads any QR code I throw at it. For the next step, I wanted to find a way to turn the url my sketch displays into a working hyperlink. I want to be able to scan the code, display the url, and click on the url and have it open in my browser. I have steps one and two, but if anyone knows how to write step 3, I'm in desperate need of some advice!
This is the first time in my life I've ever had to code (I'm studying creative writing), and I have yet to get a response on any other forums, so I'd really appreciate the help! Thank you!

Comment: It would help if you include your sketch, or portions of your sketch -- even as a screenshot if that's the only way.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about clicking on text, but there is a way to open a URL in a browser!

You use the `link()` command. I can't actually find it on the reference page, but it takes a single argument, the URL you want to open.

[Here](https://processing.org/examples/embeddedlinks.html) is the example from Processing.org.